# Parse Issue: Module 'not found'

Tags: ios, xcode, error-handling

In Xcode, I keep getting a strange error. I am using this github library: https://github.com/tapsquare/TSLibraryImport

And I am using the example code in my mediaPicker delegate method like so:

```
- (void)mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection {
    for (MPMediaItem *item in mediaItemCollection.items) {
        NSURL* assetURL = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
        NSURL* destinationURL = nil; //file URL for the location you'd like to import the asset to.
        TSLibraryImport *import = [[TSLibraryImport alloc] init];
        [import importAsset:assetURL toURL:destinationURL completionBlock:^(TSLibraryImport *theImport) {

        }];
    }
    [mediaPicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

On the `importAsset` line, I keep getting the error: Parse Issue: Module 'importAsset' not found.

Now I have dragged in TSLibraryImport.h/.m in and made sure the .m was in the compile sources but still it shows the error.

Does anyone know why this is happening? It doesn't seem to happen in the library's sample project.

Comment: Try copying over the folder, not just the two files.

Answer (score 2):

I found this question after encountering the same problem. For anyone else who runs into this issue, it turns out that recent versions of XCode (I'm using XCode 5) use import as a global variable for automatic memory management. You can fix it by renaming the TSLibraryImport pointer something else.

```
TSLibraryImport *tsImport = [[TSLibraryImport alloc] init];
```